# How to count the number of records processed by Apache Flink in a given time window

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

After defining a time window in flink as follows:

```
val lines = socket.timeWindowAll(Time.seconds(5))
```

How can I compute the number of records in that particular window of 5 seconds?

Answer (score 6):

The most efficient way to perform a count aggregation is a `ReduceFunction`. However, `reduce` has the restriction that input and output type must be identical. So you would have to convert the input to an `Int` before applying the window:

```
val socket: DataStream[(String)] = ???

val cnts: DataStream[Int] = socket
  .map(_ => 1)                    // convert to 1
  .timeWindowAll(Time.seconds(5)) // group into 5 second windows
  .reduce( (x, y) => x + y)       // sum 1s to count
```

Comment: I tried this one, but the map() function, 
map(_ => 1), 
is causing an error

"could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation[Int]"

Comment: Did you `import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._`?

Answer (score 2):

**You could try this.May be give the solution to you.**

```
val text = senv.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999)
val counts = text.map {(m: String) => (m.split(",")(0), 1) }
    .keyBy(0)
    .timeWindow(Time.seconds(10), Time.seconds(5))
    .sum(1)
counts.print
senv.execute("ProcessingTime processing example")
```

Comment: For my dataset, it is in the JSON format, so we cannot split it using a ",". That is my understanding. Please clear my doubts if I am wrong.