# Count of records in the Stream for a time window of 5s

Tags: functional-programming, apache-flink

Trying to get a count of records in the Stream for a time window of 5s. Always getting a count of 1 ??
Sent in 10 records.Expect the count to be 10 at the end.

Tried to follow the advise here from Fabian Hueske- [How to count the number of records processed by Apache Flink in a given time window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45606999/how-to-count-the-number-of-records-processed-by-apache-flink-in-a-given-time-win)

```
DataStream<Map<String, Object>> kinesisStream;
...//get data from Kinesis source into kinesisStream - works fine
final SingleOutputStreamOperator<Map<String, Object>> filterDroppedEvents = kinesisStream
    .filter(resultMap -> {
        long timestamp = Utils.getEventTimestampFromMap(resultMap);
        long currTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long driftFromCurrTS = currTimestamp - timestamp;
        if (driftFromCurrTS < 0) {
            Object eventNameObj = resultMap.get(EVENT_NAME);
            String eventName = eventNameObj != null ? (String) eventNameObj : "";
            logger.debug("PMS - event_timestamp is > current timestamp by driftFromCurrTS:{} for event_name:{} and event_timestamp:{}", driftFromCurrTS, eventName, timestamp);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });//called 10 times here - GOOD

final SingleOutputStreamOperator<CountRows> droppedEventsMapToCountRows = filterDroppedEvents
        .map(mapValue -> new CountRows(mapValue, 1L, mapValue.get(EVENT_NAME) != null ? (String) mapValue.get(EVENT_NAME) : ""));//this is called 10 times - GOOD

final KeyedStream<CountRows, String> countRowsKeyedStream = droppedEventsMapToCountRows.keyBy(new KeySelector<CountRows, String>() {
@Override
public String getKey(CountRows countRows) throws Exception {
logger.info("Inside getKey");
return countRows.getEventName();
}
});//doesn't get in here to this logger statement ??

final AllWindowedStream<CountRows, TimeWindow> countRowsTimeWindowAllWindowedStream =  countRowsKeyedStream
        .timeWindowAll(org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time.Time.seconds(5));
//.sum("count")
final SingleOutputStreamOperator<CountRows> countRowsReduceStream = countRowsTimeWindowAllWindowedStream.reduce((accum, input) -> {
            logger.info("Inside reduce");
            return new CountRows(input.getRow(), accum.getCount() + input.getCount(), input.getEventName());// sum 1s to count
        });//don't see this logger statement "Inside reduce"

DataStream<InfluxDBPoint> droppedEventsStream =
        countRowsReduceStream.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<CountRows, InfluxDBPoint>() {
    @Override
    public void flatMap(CountRows countRows, Collector<InfluxDBPoint> out) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Inside final map"); // only called once and countRows.getCount() is 1 - BAD - want it to be 10 ??
        Map<String, Object> mapValue = countRows.getRow();
        //long currTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Object eventTSObj = mapValue.get(EVENT_TIMESTAMP);
        String eventTimestamp = eventTSObj != null ? (String)eventTSObj : "";
        long eventTS = Utils.getLongFromDateStr(eventTimestamp);
        Map<String, String> tags = new HashMap<>();
        Object eventNameObj = mapValue.get(Utils.EVENT_NAME);
        String eventName = eventNameObj != null ? (String)eventNameObj : "";
        tags.put(Utils.EVENT_NAME, eventName);
        Map<String, Object> fields = new HashMap<>();
        fields.put("count", countRows.getCount());
        out.collect(new InfluxDBPoint("dropped_events_count", eventTS, tags, fields));//TODO: measurement name
    }
});
        /* Tried map but doesn't work
reduceStream.map(countRows -> {
            logger.info("Inside final map");
            Map<String, Object> mapValue = countRows.getRow();
            //long currTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Object eventTSObj = mapValue.get(EVENT_TIMESTAMP);
            String eventTimestamp = eventTSObj != null ? (String)eventTSObj : "";
            long eventTS = Utils.getLongFromDateStr(eventTimestamp);
            Map<String, String> tags = new HashMap<>();
            Object eventNameObj = mapValue.get(Utils.EVENT_NAME);
            String eventName = eventNameObj != null ? (String)eventNameObj : "";
            tags.put(Utils.EVENT_NAME, eventName);
            Map<String, Object> fields = new HashMap<>();
            fields.put("count", countRows.getCount());
            return new InfluxDBPoint("dropped_events_count", eventTS, tags, fields);//TODO: measurement name
        });*/
droppedEventsStream.addSink(influxSink);
```

@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

CountRows is a POJO wrapper around the Map<String, Object> to add the count:

```
public static class CountRows implements Serializable, Comparable<CountRows> {
        Map<String, Object> row;
        Long count;
        String eventName;
  //default constructor and constructor with 3 attributes
```

.........

TIA,

Answer (score 0):

One thing that stands out is that you are using `timeWindowAll` with a `KeyedStream`. This is not how this part of the API should be used. If you wish to compute a global count across all of the keys, then remove the `keyBy`; if you wish to count the events for each key separately, then keep the `keyBy` and use `timeWindow` rather than `timeWindowAll`.

I also see that you have event time timestamps, but don't appear to be using event time windows (since I don't see a timestamp assigner or watermark generator). I can't tell if that's intentional, or possibly related to why the results don't match your expectations.

Comment: I  already had a Watermark assigner:
monitoringDataStreamSource = env.addSource(....)
kinesisStream = monitoringDataStreamSource
                    .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new MonitoringTSWAssigner(bound));
I changed to use timeWindow but I am still getting only 1 record.

Comment: You haven't shared enough for us to be able to figure out what's going on.